# How to deal with possible zone changes when converting LatLong to UTM, adding offset to UTM, and converting offset UTM back to LatLong?

Tags: python, coordinates, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, utm

I'm trying to accomplish a fairly simple goal, which is that I have a starting LatLong coordinate, I convert this into UTM, thus ending up with some particular zone number and letter (I'm using the [Python library UTM](https://github.com/Turbo87/utm)), I offset the UTM eastings and northings by some values, and then convert everything back into LatLong. This generally seems to work fine, except for edge conditions if my offset causes the current UTM coordinates to go out of bounds of the current zone and into a new zone.

I'm very new to working with these geographical coordinate systems, so does it even make sense for me to say can I do offsets while preserving the current zone, or does it loop back around? Is it possible to have UTM coordinates that are technically out of bounds within the current zone, but convert properly back to the proper Lat/Long coordinates, or will they be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can share your code, someone can help you more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have coordinates outside zone, see e.g. the subsection [Overlapping grids in UTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#Overlapping_grids).

In fact, such coordinate system (or better the MGRS) was designed also for such cases: on a military ground (battles) you should not care much about changing zones or to do transformations (and so spheric or ellipsoid coordinates).

Just test that your libraries allows such values: some libraries are more strict (they may requires normalized coordinates). By UTM design they should allows coordinates outside proper zone, but a test is always better.